# Calling multiple commands in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[This is my command.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FupN7.png)[After entering the command nothing happened][2]I want to automate the commands in putty so i have written the commands in a shell script and called it from a batch file

```
echo -e "password" | sudo -S screen -ls  
pwd 
cd ..
```

these are the commands in shell script,
but the commands `pwd`, `cd`  are not executing after `sudo` commands..... No commands are working under `sudo` commands

Comment: How do you execute your script? You wrote *batch* file, which means a script file windows `cmd`, was this just a typo? Do the exact same commands work when entered directly in `bash`?

Comment: putty.exe -ssh user@hostname -pw password -m myshell.sh -t                   this is the command in batch file .

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you launch screen and the process never exits so the bash script cannot move forward to the `pwd` and `cd` commands

As a workaround you may write down your commands into the shell script and execute it in screen using

```
screen -d -m bash ./script.sh
```

Comment: I have tried this comment but nothing happened , I have attached the screen shot

Comment: what do you expect from the "screen" program? Why do you use it?